# Is there a way to make Skype show my contacts instead of my history in the sidebar?

Tags: skype, gui

`<rant>` that new Skype on OSX is so amazingly awful its not even funny...`</rant>`

Alright then, so, the most amazing feat of the new Skype version 5 is that whenever it starts up, it immediately shows me just about the most useless information possible: A log of my last conversation. Chances are, the last thing I did was to make a Skype call so all Skype shows me is a long list of `Call Started` and `Call Ended`. Amazingly useful.

Actually, I probably started up Skype to make a call to someone, so the information I would like to see is the list of available contacts. Now the best thing would be to actually put this list in the sidebar, where it would be readily available no matter what I was doing last. Instead, Skype puts a history of all recent conversations there which might or might not contain the desired contact. At any rate, I have to scan that whole list to search for the desired contact every time I open up Skype, then I find out that the contact is not in there, hit the contacts icon in the top left and then *finally* can start making the call.

Is there a way to just put the list of contacts in the sidebar and make Skype behave again?

Answer (score 0):

Just click on your username above the log. This will switch the view. I call it a "hidden" feature. Like the "hidden" feature in MS Office 2k7 where the file menu has this nice Microsoft Logo. It is just not a good design of the gui.

Comment: My username is in the top left corner, the log of the last conversation I had is in the 'main' window towards the bottom right, but there is no username above that log. What exactly do you mean?